# Self generic type

Tags: c#

I'm building the following class:

```
abstract class Foo
{
    protected abstract void Process(FooProcessor<T> processor)
}
```

What I need is to make `T` be the type of child `Foo` class:

```
class FooChild : Foo
{
    protected override void Process(FooProcessor<FooChild> processor)
    {
    }
}
```

Is it achievable? If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like a self-constraint will allow you to expose derived types and also constrain at the same time:

```
abstract class Foo<T> where T : Foo<T>
{
    protected abstract void Process(FooProcessor<T> processor);
}
```

Then derived types define themselves as the target:

```
class FooChild : Foo<FooChild>
{
    protected override void Process(FooProcessor<FooChild> processor)
    {
    }
}
```

Please note though that this design tends to only have a small set of uses. Also, you lose the ability to refer to `Foo` as a base without specifying it's generic type.

There is also a [blog post from Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx) about how it is possible to abuse this design, so you might want to consider what it is you are actually trying to achieve by wanting to have your protected method reference the derived class directly.

You may be better off using interfaces to encapsulate the behaviour you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't think its possible, because Foo is generic - there is no non-generic Foo class

Comment: @SergeyMetlov I've seen this approach taken before to be able to expose a strongly-typed reference to a derived class from a base type, it always feels a little backwards, and being honest I've not personally needed to use this approach.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Apologies, I forgot the generic argument on the `Foo` constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You mean this:

```
class FooProcessor<T>
{
}

abstract class Foo<T>
{
    protected abstract void Process(FooProcessor<T> processor);
}

class FooChild : Foo<FooChild>
{
    protected override void Process(FooProcessor<FooChild> processor)
    {
    }
}
```

It would be easier to implement with an interface:

```
interface FooProcessor<T>
{
}

interface Foo<T>
{
    void Process(FooProcessor<T> processor);
}

class FooChild : Foo<FooChild>
{
    void Foo<FooChild>.Process(FooProcessor<FooChild> processor)
    {
        this.Process((FooProcessorFooChild)processor);
    }

    protected void Process(FooProcessorFooChild processor)
    {
    }
}

class FooProcessorFooChild : FooProcessor<FooChild>
{
}
```

Comment: `FooChild : Foo<FooChild>` that is quite strange.. Is there a way to avoid such confusing signature?

Comment: @SergeyMetlov: Is the second one better? Note I personally would prefer the first one.

Comment: The same as for me. Even more complex.

Comment: @SergeyMetlov: I agree, but the signature is more obvious. Will remove it since you didn't like it. I think there is nothing you can further do about it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Actually, please don't remove it. Without the alternative, some of the comments in here don't make any sense any more to future readers.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: rolled back!